# How to use null with kotlin @Parcelize

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, kotlin-android-extensions

Here is very simple code:

```
@Parcelize
data class Inner(val a: Int): Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class Test(val a: Int, val inner: Inner?): Parcelable

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    fun testParcel() {
        val test = Test(0, null)

        val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
        parcel.writeParcelable(test, test.describeContents())
    }
}
```

I have nullable property `Test.inner`. If it is not null, the code works fine but when it is null then I have the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.os.Parcelable.writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel, int)' on a null object reference
```

How to resolve this? Maybe I do something wrong.

Comment: Is these files are in test folder or androidTest folder ?

Comment: @SangeetSuresh It is in androidTest

Comment: it's a bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20032

Comment: @SilviaH You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug has been [fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20032) in Kotlin 1.1.60.

Comment: It has happened to me with Kotlin 1.3.11 :/

Comment: And also with 1.3.21 !

Comment: hit the bug in 1.3.50